# hide duplicate row sql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, duplicates

i have problem about duplicate row.

[image]

And my purpose like this:

[image]

Can you help me sir what the query to do like that?

The code I have been using is as follows:

```
select a.id_task1, b.id_task, b.task, b.cycle_sequence_number, c.cycle_sequence_number FROM task_table a LEFT OUTER JOIN billing_cycle b ON (a.id_task1=b.id_task) LEFT OUTER JOIN header c ON (b.cycle_sequence_number = c.cycle_sequence_number) where a.id_task1< 23 order by b.cycle_sequence_number DESC;
```

Regards,
-Tri-

---

Sorry sir, i forgot post my code:

```
select a.id_task1, b.id_task, b.task, b.cycle_sequence_number, c.cycle_sequence_number
FROM task_table a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN billing_cycle b ON (a.id_task1=b.id_task) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN header c ON (b.cycle_sequence_number = c.cycle_sequence_number) 
where a.id_task1< 23
order by b.cycle_sequence_number DESC;
```

Comment: You should paste your code textually to enable us to paste it. No one will type in your code from a picture. Also, your code needs to be on this page because your picture might long be off-line when this question still exists. Your question is un-related to phpmyadmin, it is a MySQL-specific question and you need to be more specific about your needs.

Comment: Sorry sir, i forget it.. wait i paste my code.

Comment: I have edited your question, changed the tags to mysql and duplicates from phpmyadmin, since it is not related to phpmyadmin, it is a problem with duplicates in a mysql query. Now your question starts to have some quality, therefore I have up-voted it.

Answer (score 1):

In relational databases the results of your queries are relations/tables ('relation' and 'table' are synonymous expressions). So, let's name your query and use `group by`s:

```
select id_task1, id_task, task, max(b.cycle_sequence_number) as b_cycle_sequence_number, max(c.cycle_sequence_number) as c_cycle_sequence_number
from (...) t
group by id_task1, id_task, task
order by b_cycle_sequence_number
```

You should interpret `b.cycle_sequence_number` as `b_cycle_sequence_number` and `c.cycle_sequence_number` as `c_cycle_sequence_number` to avoid duplicate column names. I'm sorry for not rewriting your actual code, but I refuse to type in your code from a picture.

Edit: The real code is:

```
select a.id_task1, b.id_task, b.task, b.cycle_sequence_number, c.cycle_sequence_number FROM task_table a LEFT OUTER JOIN billing_cycle b ON (a.id_task1=b.id_task) LEFT OUTER JOIN header c ON (b.cycle_sequence_number = c.cycle_sequence_number) where a.id_task1< 23 order by b.cycle_sequence_number DESC;
```

Suggestion:

```
SELECT id_task1, id_task, task, max(b.cycle_sequence_number) as b_cycle_sequence_number, max(c.cycle_sequence_number) as c_cycle_sequence_number
FROM (SELECT a.id_task1, b.id_task, b.task, b.cycle_sequence_number as b_cycle_sequence_number, c.cycle_sequence_number as c_cycle_sequence_number
      FROM task_table a 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN billing_cycle b 
      ON (a.id_task1=b.id_task) 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN header c 
      ON (b.cycle_sequence_number = c.cycle_sequence_number) where a.id_task1< 23) t
GROUP BY id_task1, id_task, task
ORDER BY b_cycle_sequence_number
```

Comment: Many thanks sir..  I am sorry if i wrong rule about my question. Coz i am nerveous. This is the first time i ask in forum international. :)

Comment: @TryArfandyBs, no need to be nervous, everybody has to start things somewhere. If my answer solved your problem, then you might consider marking it as the correct answer, so others will know this is the solution.

Comment: @TryArfandyBs, based on your code I have made a suggestion, see my edited answer.

Comment: i am from indonesian, if u want visit indonesian, i am open for u.. Coz u are good person..

Comment: @TryArfandyBs, I am glad to help. You seem to be a nice fellow.